# Submit a Comment to Disqus Using Webform - How?

Tags: forms, disqus

I have a form on a page that will allow the user to submit feedback to me. What I would like to know is if I can take the content of the form and automatically have it post to Disqus that is on the same page and do this *without* using SSO (Single Sign-On).

I am using a hosted CMS so using SSO isn't easily possible because I don't have the server side access required. This is why I am asking about a method to do this without using SSO.

My thought is when they submit the form it would post the comment similar to the way it works when I import comments into a site. The comments have their name and comment but they must claim their comment to show their avatar, etc.

Is this possible? Basically I am looking for a client side only way to post comments to a Disqus thread using the Disqus API.